# Where is the claw for the 'Speaking with Silence' quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm an currently in Snow Veil Sanctum and I'm having trouble finishing the **Speaking with Silence** quest. During this quest I'm supposed to lead Mercer Frey into Snow Veil Sanctum to kill Karliah, a former Thieves Guild initiate. I've already made my way to the end of the ruins where I battle a multitude of Draugs and learn the 'weapon, disarm' word. Unfortunately, I still can't get to Karliah because she's behind a door that requires a claw to open. I've killed everything up to this point and nothing has dropped a claw. Where am I supposed to get this thing? Is it in the ruins somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mercer is supposed to open it for you. You may have to push him to the door to get him to unlock it.

Seems to be a [common](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/52479/t1696096-stuck-thieves-guild-speaking-with-silence/) [problem](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/60976543).

Comment: Yup, had to push the bastard all the way from the beginning of the room. Haha, fail. Thanks!

Comment: I've gotten him all the way up and touching the door but he never does anything?